# Which Object's Array Has Most of Particular Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, set, nsarray, pfobject

I have an Object that contains many pieces of information, a Title String, Date String, and NSArray, amongst others.  This Object has 8 different sets of this information.  I want to find out which Set's Title has the most occurrences of the word "Sunday".  After the data loads, I run some calculations:

```
NSArray *yourArrayhere = self.theObject[@"DatesSuggested"];
    int occurrences = 0;
    for(NSString *string in yourArrayhere){
        occurrences += ([string isEqualToString:@"Sunday"]?1:0); //certain object is @"Sunday"
    }
    NSLog(@"number of occurences %d", occurrences);
```

In Console, it gives me a printout of the number of times Sunday is found in each NSArray from that Object's 8 sets.  How would I then best go about getting the title for the Set in the Object that contains the most occurrences?

Each set in the Object appears like this in the console:

```
<Activities: 0x7fc3abe107a0, objectId: 6eUXy9SkZK, localId: (null)> {
    DatesSuggested =     (
        Sunday,
        Sunday
    );
    Title = Train;
    VotesAgainst = 0;
    VotesFor = 0;
}
```

Here's the entire Console Log for the PFObject:

```
2016-06-23 22:51:10.399 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] Bar D
2016-06-23 22:51:10.400 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] <Activities: 0x7fb33a61f190, objectId: NZ1JNtDoIR, localId: (null)> {
    DatesSuggested =     (
    );
    Title = "Bar D";
    VotesAgainst = 0;
    VotesFor = 1;
}
2016-06-23 22:51:10.402 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] Creede Trip
2016-06-23 22:51:10.402 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] <Activities: 0x7fb33a620650, objectId: VAu5qpGYLk, localId: (null)> {
    Title = "Creede Trip";
    VotesAgainst = 0;
    VotesFor = 0;
}
2016-06-23 22:51:10.403 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] Durango Shopping
2016-06-23 22:51:10.403 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] <Activities: 0x7fb33a620b10, objectId: sCKWlnI3Z7, localId: (null)> {
    Title = "Durango Shopping";
    VotesAgainst = 0;
    VotesFor = 0;
}
2016-06-23 22:51:10.404 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] Fishing
2016-06-23 22:51:10.404 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] <Activities: 0x7fb33a621310, objectId: Qy4zmA7jir, localId: (null)> {
    Title = Fishing;
    VotesAgainst = 0;
    VotesFor = 0;
}
2016-06-23 22:51:10.405 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] Ouray Trip
2016-06-23 22:51:10.406 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] <Activities: 0x7fb33a621880, objectId: Nmrw405JZo, localId: (null)> {
    Title = "Ouray Trip";
    VotesAgainst = 0;
    VotesFor = 0;
}
2016-06-23 22:51:10.407 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] Pagosa Shopping
2016-06-23 22:51:10.407 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] <Activities: 0x7fb33a621df0, objectId: ws0UbFwTtZ, localId: (null)> {
    Title = "Pagosa Shopping";
    VotesAgainst = 0;
    VotesFor = 0;
}
2016-06-23 22:51:10.408 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] Rapids
2016-06-23 22:51:10.408 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] <Activities: 0x7fb33a622300, objectId: UUxHmqYOM9, localId: (null)> {
    Title = Rapids;
    VotesAgainst = 0;
    VotesFor = 0;
}
2016-06-23 22:51:10.409 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] Train
2016-06-23 22:51:10.410 Roll 'Em Up[1675:150331] <Activities: 0x7fb33a622870, objectId: 6eUXy9SkZK, localId: (null)> {
    DatesSuggested =     (
    );
    Title = Train;
    VotesAgainst = 0;
    VotesFor = 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

The code I use to get the PFObject and populate table is:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activities"];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
    }

    [query orderByAscending:@"Title"];
    return query;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.



// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    self.theObject = object;

   //Code for the Cell Text removed for brevity

    [self performCalculations];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @matt See Edit to OP for that info.

Comment: @matt What I posted is one of the 8 sets.  The others show up, but only one at a time, when I set the NSLog to the PFObject that contains them all.

Comment: @matt edited it a little bit so you can see what I see in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written a function that counts occurrances of an object.  Just generalize it a bit...

```
- (NSInteger)occurrencesOf:(NSString *)string inArray:(NSArray *)array {
    NSInteger occurrences = 0;
    for(NSString *s in array){
        occurrences += ([s isEqualToString:string]?1:0);
    }
    NSLog(@"number of occurences %d", occurrences);
    return occurrences;
}
```

Put the object's arrays you want to test into an array, like this:

```
NSArray *arrays = @[object.array0, object.array1, ... .array8];
```

The pattern to maximize a function is to set an impossibly low max, and record the parameter that exceeds it...

```
NSArray *maxOccurrenceArray = nil; 
NSInteger maxOccurrences = -LONG_MAX;
for (NSArray *array in arrays) {
    NSInteger occurrences = [self occurrencesOf:@"Sunday" inArray:array];
    if (occurrences > maxOccurrences) {
        maxOccurrences = occurrences;
        maxOccurrenceArray = array;
    }
}
NSLog(@"The array with the most occurrences is %@", maxOccurrenceArray);
```

**EDIT** I'd advise getting out of the PFQueryTableVC for this test -- and, really, abandoning it altogether.  It's a "convenience" class that will get in your way, ultimately.  I understand for now that its a head-start, and you may not know enough yet to do without it.

Anyway, in viewWillAppear, just do this:

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

PFQuery *query = [self queryForTable];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"this should be all of the objects %@", objects];
    // now just run the code I suggest, adapting objects as the array of arrays

    NSArray *maxOccurrenceArray = nil; 
    NSInteger maxOccurrences = -LONG_MAX;
    for (PFObject *pfObject in objects) {
        NSArray *array = [pfObject objectForKey:@"THE_NAME_OF_THE_ARRAY_PROPERTY"];
        NSInteger occurrences = [self occurrencesOf:@"Sunday" inArray:array];
        if (occurrences > maxOccurrences) {
            maxOccurrences = occurrences;
            maxOccurrenceArray = array;
       }
    }
    NSLog(@"The array with the most occurrences is %@", maxOccurrenceArray);
}];
```

Comment: I have added that to code but get the NSLog of "The array with the most occurrences is (null)".  The Log for "number of occurrences" never gets called.

Comment: Most likely the array of arrays is not getting initialized correctly. Can you check that?

Comment: That is the problem.  The initial object is a PFObject, not a true NSArray.  One of the elements of that PFObject is an NSArray that contains the vote for Sundays.  I believe that is where the issue is happening, as I don't know how to do the 2nd step you mentioned, to make an array of the 8 different NSArrays contained within the PFObject.

Comment: In your test, you used different arrays for yourArrayHere. However you got 8 of those, just line them up separated by commas inside the braces @[]

Comment: The console printed those out when I put in the NSLog for the section of code running it.  I called that section of code from the cellForRowAtIndexPath, to make sure that I didn't run the code until the PFObject was returned.  Therefore, that section of code is running 8 times, because of 8 different rows in the table, corresponding to the entries in PFObject.  How would I modify it to group them all together in one?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing more code.  It sounds like you're getting one object at a time from your table view cellForRow method?  That's probably a design mistake.  Get all N objects earlier like viewWillAppear, and place them into an NSArray property.  That array can be your table's datasource and its the input to the code I suggest.

Comment: I'll have to check when I get back home on computer to see if I can. The way it retrieves the PFObject is different, as I have tried to get that in viewDidAppear before but it ran the code too quickly.

Comment: Ok, I added the code showing how I get the PFObject, and anything relative to that.

Comment: ok.  see edit.  this is just test code i'm suggesting.  I also suggest you learn how to use Parse with a regular UIViewController that has a table view.  The class they offer is pretty terrible, imo.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that it isn't the greatest.  Apparently the array is not getting named, though, as the result I get is "The array with the most occurrences is (
)
"