# Determine Which Object Has Most of One String

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsarray, pfobject

I use Parse.com and have a PFObject that I use to populate a TableView.  The PFObject contains several NSStrings and one NSArray.  The array will contain days of week, some of which occur multiple times.  I just need a way to determine which object has the most of each day of the week in that Array.  I have had some success with finding the most popular one, but it gives numbers for the title of array.

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

PFQuery *query = [self queryForTable];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"this should be all of the objects %@", objects];
    // now just run the code I suggest, adapting objects as the array of arrays

    NSArray *maxOccurrenceArray = nil; 
    NSInteger maxOccurrences = -LONG_MAX;
    for (PFObject *pfObject in objects) {
        NSArray *array = [pfObject objectForKey:@"THE_NAME_OF_THE_ARRAY_PROPERTY"];
        NSInteger occurrences = [self occurrencesOf:@"Sunday" inArray:array];
        if (occurrences > maxOccurrences) {
            maxOccurrences = occurrences;
            maxOccurrenceArray = array;
       }
    }
    NSLog(@"The array with the most occurrences is %@", maxOccurrenceArray);
}];
NSArray *maxOccurrenceArray = nil; 
NSInteger maxOccurrences = -LONG_MAX;
for (NSArray *array in arrays) {
    NSInteger occurrences = [self occurrencesOf:@"Sunday" inArray:array];
    if (occurrences > maxOccurrences) {
        maxOccurrences = occurrences;
        maxOccurrenceArray = array;
    }
}
NSLog(@"The array with the most occurrences is %@", maxOccurrenceArray);
```

Comment: It's disappointing to see my answer (here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38006070/294949) copied into this question.  As skim your recent questions, I notice the you get answers, engage in comment q&a, never mark anything correct, and then re-ask with variations supplied by others.  I think those reviewing this history will -- at a minimum -- be unmotivated to provide much assistance.

Comment: And by the way, I think you asked this same question to me in long commentary under the answer that supplied this copied code).  It's not clear what you mean by the "title of the array".  Arrays don't have titles.  (Maybe you mean the property name `@"THE_NAME_OF_THE_ARRAY_PROPERTY"` ?? If that's the result you're looking for then for goodness sakes, write that string down as `maxOccurencePropertyName` instead of the `maxOccurrenceArray` when the current max value is exceeded.  The question makes one wonder if you made any effort at all to understand the code you copied.

Comment: I had no real choice but to submit a new question, as you abandoned the conversation, wouldn't start up a conversation in chat, and even commented as such that you were done with anything to do with me.

Comment: I think you've got me mixed up with someone else

Comment: You had been communicating pretty regularly with me...I even left a last comment 12 minutes after you left yours...no response for 2 full days, I clicked the let's start this conversation in chat button, never showed.  I have code that doesn't work, gotta get help from somewhere.